# NPOI not write all cells out or removed wrong row

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using NPOI 2.1.3.1 to write out a workbook but I got a blank header after write to file.

Detailed operation is:

1. Load an existing xlsx file into memory

   Workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(stream);
2. I took the first row/header to lookup some values, but don't change anything on it.

   var firstRow = sheet.GetRow(sheet.FirstRowNum);
   var columns = GetColumns(firstRow);
   // Set other cells, but didn't touch the header...
3. Removed the **2nd row** and create a new row as the 2nd row.

   sheet.RemoveRow(row);
   sheet.CreateRow(1);
4. Save the workbook to another file using `Write` method.

**The problem is the saved file is missing the header values.**
[image]

**And when I debug into the code and check the workbook after the `Write`**
[image]

The header cells were still there. What happened for `Write` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is confirmed as a bug for NPOI.

`ISheet.RemoveRow` has removed wrong row from underlying data list.

I've submited [pull request](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/pull/91) and hopefully can be resolved in next release of NPOI.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in 2.2.1 and available in NuGet version 2.2.1

Comment: I still got same issue although I use 2.2.1. The removed row is blank but not removed completely.